# Trying to create multiple animated kebab menu with dropdown list not working in Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-8

if you need more details you can ask. Thanks in advance
In laravel 8 I have a button called, create app when I click it, it takes me to the page adds some data. When i add data it shows me many app lata in listview. In every list view, I have an animated kebab menu  [image: you can see it in this image]. But the problem is when i create new app dropdown list only works for last enter apps. so it means if i create 10 apps dropdown list will work for only last app i have enterd it will not work for other 9. [image: in this image you can see dropdown is not woring for 2nd app]

here is some code of my index.blade.php which can create multipul kebab menu but not works for dropdown

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                {{-- <div class="card-body row"> --}}
                    <form action="{{ route('products.destroy', $product->id) }}" method="POST">
                        {{-- <ul class="nav"> --}}
                            <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="{{ route('products.edit', $product->id) }}">
                                <br>
                                <img src="/logo/{{ $product->logo }}" width="100px" class="col-4">
                                <div class="col-2" style="color: #1d2124">
                                    <strong >App Name:- {{ $product->name }}</strong>
                                    <br>
                                    <strong>App Id:- {{ $product->id }}</strong>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <div class="kebab">
                                    <figure></figure>
                                    <figure class="middle"></figure>
                                    <p class="cross">x</p>
                                    <figure></figure>
                                    <ul class="dropdown">
                                        @csrf
                                        @method('DELETE')
                                        <li><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></li>
                                        <li><a href="api/json_link">All Json</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="api/SearchById">JsonById</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="api/SearchByName">JsonByName</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {{-- </ul> --}}
                    </form>
                {{-- </div> --}}
            </div>
        @endforeach
```

here is javescript code which can create kabeb menu for all app but dropdown for last inserted app in app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

require('alpinejs');
var kebab = document.querySelector(".kebab"),
    middle = document.querySelector(".middle"),
    cross = document.querySelector(".cross"),
    dropdown = document.querySelector(".dropdown");

kebab.addEventListener("click", function() {
    middle.classList.toggle("active");
    cross.classList.toggle("active");
    dropdown.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` only returns the last DOM element matching your selector. If you want to apply a dropdown menu for every kebab, you have to use

```
kebabs = document.querySelectorAll(".kebab")
...
kebabs.foreach(this.addEventListener("click", function(){
   //do what you want
})
```